# Non manifold structure

Tags: modeling

I tried to create a manifold structure but Blender keeps complaining that the structure is not manifold. I can't figure out what to do as according to what I see, it is manifold.
What are the steps to have it watertight?[structure bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSC29.png)

[image: structure top]

[image: non-manifold]
[image: Non-manifold 2]

Comment: In the picture of the bottom I see overlapping faces. Are you sure you did check the model?

Comment: I created all the faces from bottom to the cylinder myself, one by one. First the inner and the outer faces after that. I'm not sure what to look for, If I choose "Make manifold" in the 3D print menu, Blender removes the cylinder and all faces connecting to the bottom structure

Comment: Can you go into edit mode, deselect all, then choose _`Select > Select by Trait > Non Manifold`_ and post result

Comment: @batFINGER I'm starting to see where I made a mistake: I didn't remove the existing faces before linking the cylinder to the bottom structure